# Rails + simple_form nested object with cocoon. How to sort objects with errors and display it first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I have a join table with simple form. With nested has_many :through association. I add multiply objects with cocoon gem.

It renders like:

```
<%= v.simple_fields_for :document_place_rooms do |vf| %>
  <%= render partial: 'document_place_room', locals: {f: vf, document: document} %>
<% end %>
```

If all objects are valid every things renders fine, with default order.

But, if one of objects invalid, render :edit template and the invalid object sort last in the list. No matter where the order be when create, it renders last if it invalid and re render in edit template.

I think this happens because default order is by id, but if object not saved (invalid), it has no id and it pushed last of list. I try change default scope of join model, but no result.

Please help, how can i sort the objects, that have no ids, and pushed it first in the list of nested object?

Comment: A default-scope sorts on the database, so that might explain why the unsaved/invalid items always appear at the end. I have never used default-scope in such a case, and in general I seem to remember failed forms are re-rendered in exactly the same order (without default-scope). Maybe you can try/verify that?